# Error Connecting to 2 Org Local Fabric With IBM Blockchain Platform

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to run a basic projects i am using ibm blockchain platform v2.0.8 on ubuntu 18

in the start it was running better but some time later its started to give an error `[ERROR] Failed to start 2 Org Local Fabric: Error: Environment failed to become available. Please check the Docker container logs for more details.` In details on container log there is no such error that is why its very challenging to me to understand why it is happening.

[Complete Docker Log Click Here...](https://gist.github.com/ibrahimq21/f2db6469296adbf989a2f6010a621a56)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the network configuration of the dns was changed therefore it throws an error.